# Why do I get unexpected hour when substracting two times

Tags: php, datetime

I have this simple function to subtract time: the input values are:

```
$current = '23:48:32';
$arrival = '23:41:48';

$time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($current) - strtotime($arrival));
$waitingTime = $time; // 21:06:44
```

Looks like the diff for the minutes is correct, I am not sure why I am getting the 21 in front of the minutes. It should be `00:06:44`.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using $waitingTime in the last line, after setting $time to the result of calling the date function?

Comment: check my correction..

Comment: I can't [reproduce the problem](https://eval.in/40060). Also your "correction" doesn't make sense. Care to give the logic behind it ?

Comment: i'd not recommend using the `date` function to retrieve time differences.  simply subtract the two dates like you have to get the seconds difference.  then use some simple division to determine days

Comment: the logic is i get the arrival time  then i want subttract from current time to find out how many minutes has the person been waiting. Simple calculation to find out the waiting time in a doctor's office.

Comment: I tested your code in local everything is ok!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `gmdate()`

```
$time = gmdate( "H:i:s", strtotime($current) - strtotime($arrival));
```

Comment: If i wan to get the difference only in minutes without showing the hour, how would i do that?

Comment: change the `"H:i:s"` to `"i:s"`

Comment: what if the waiting time went over one hour, the hour will not show, that's a problem. If the waiting time has passed from one hour i want to calculate  that in minutes.

Comment: @user1960170 This is really basic and if you don't know how to do it you can always search for examples/solutions on the net. I'll give you a hint: use `explode()` and do some math.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect this code to give you an interval.

the `strtotime($current) - strtotime($arrival)` line calculates a interval in seconds but when you pass it to `date` it assumes your speaking of an interval since epoch. so you get timezone translated value for `$time`; you must have gotten 9 because your probably behind `UTC`

use `strtotime($current) - strtotime($arrival) / 3600` for hours and remainder divide by 60 for minutes. and then seconds

Comment: tl;dr: `date()` is helpfully factoring in your timezone, which is causing a strange hours value.

Answer (score 1):

That's why PHP has [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) & [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/DateInterval)s:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$current = '23:48:32';
$arrival = '23:41:48';

$current = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $current);
$arrival = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $arrival);

$diff = $current->diff($arrival);

unset($current, $arrival);

echo $diff->format('%H:%I:%S');
?>
```

Output:

```
00:06:44
```

Answer (score 1):

This code echo `00:06:44`!

```
$current='23:48:32';
$arrival='23:41:48';

$time = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($current) - strtotime($arrival));
echo $time;//00:06:44
```

What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I think your server is using GMT+0 timezone so there are no issues.

Comment: You tried `$current='23:48:32 GMT';
$arrival='23:41:48 GMT';`?